# How to save Sent Items to folder of SentOnBehalfName mailbox in Office 365?

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

At work we send emails from Shared Inboxes. The emails would go into the user's own Sent Items instead of that of the Shared Inbox.

I wrote some VBA code which sorted this issue. We are moving to Outlook 365 & the code is not working there.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then     'If Item is a MailItem
        If Item.SentOnBehalfOfName <> "" Then   'And if Item is Sent on Behalf of an inbox
            'Save the sent email in the Sent Items folder for the inbox in question
            Item.SaveSentMessageFolder GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(Item.SentOnBehalfOfName).Folders("Sent Items")

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried

```vb
msgbox GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(Item.SentOnBehalfOfName).Folders("Sent Items").Name
```

It gives the name of the folder but the Sent Item does not go there.

I created a "Test" folder & saved to the folder ignoring Item.SentOnBehalfOfName & this works if the "Test" folder is in my own inbox but not if it is in a Shared Inbox.

I tried changing the code to use Set & to include Application as per below.

```vb
Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(Item.SentOnBehalfOfName).Folders("Sent Items")
```

Comment: Did you try to set the property before the item is submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ThisOutlookSession module add the following variable declaration:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
```

If you don't already have an `Application_Startup` event procedure create it by selecting `Application` in the left dropdown over the code area & `Startup` in the right dropdown over the code area.

The code to add to this procedure:

```
Set Items = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
```

Then in the left dropdown over the code area you need to select `Items` & in the right dropdown over the code area select `ItemSend`.

Below is what this procedure should look like:

```vb
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then     'If Item is a MailItem
        If Item.SentOnBehalfOfName <> Session.Accounts.Item(1).CurrentUser Then   'And if Item is Sent on Behalf of the users own inbox
            'Move the email into the Sent Items folder for the inbox in question
            Item.Move GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(Item.SentOnBehalfOfName).Folders("Sent Items")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a folder from a single store, there is no way to set a folder from another store/account. If you want to get items saved to another store, you must save them first and then move them programmatically to another folder/store.

Also, I'd suggest setting the [MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.savesentmessagefolder) property before an item is submitted:

```
Sub SetSentFolder()  
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailITem  
 Dim myResponse As Outlook.MailITem  
 Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder  
 Dim mpf As Outlook.Folder 

 Set mpfInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)  
 Set mpf = mpfInbox.Folders.Add("SaveMyPersonalItems")  
 Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem  
 Set myResponse = myItem.Reply  
 myResponse.Display  
 myResponse.To = "Eugene Astafiev"  
 Set myResponse.SaveSentMessageFolder = mpf  
 myResponse.Send  
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Eugene,Thanks for your idea but it doesn't work & it makes sense why - these are emails that I'm sending so the code errors out with setting myResponse to myItem.Reply.

Comment: This is a sample code showing that you need to try setting the `SaveSentMessageFolder` property before sending.

Comment: Hi Eugene, a user could have multiple shared inboxes so can't really set SaveSentMessageFolder before sending. I suppose you could have the user run a macro but that would mean making an automated process manual which would be far from ideal & I don't think they'd bother doing it to be honest.

Comment: I have just figured out that you are trying to set a folder from another store in Outlook. I don't think it is possible at all. You must deal only with folders from the single store.

Comment: Hi Eugene, if that's the case it's unfortunate & I can't understand why this has changed in 365. This code is being used with Outlook 2013 with no issues.